# Create C# Wrapper for Javascript Library

Tags: c#, javascript

I'm looking for an automated way to create a simple C# wrapper for an existing JavaScript library. I want to create a string of JavaScript using a C# class on the server, then send the JavaScript to the client.

Example: 
I’m creating charts using the KendoUI JavaScript library.  I’m creating the JavaScript to render the charts server side because a single page can render infinitely many charts based on how the user chooses to configure the chart.

The JavaScript string that is being generated server side looks like this (greatly simplified for example):

```
function createChart() {
    $("#chart").kendoChart({
        title: {
            text: "Chart Title",                        
        },                   
        series: [{
            field: "Cost"
        }],                   
        categoryAxis: {
            field: "StartDate",
        }                    
    });
}
```

Right now my C# code is simply building a string to create the JavaScript string (greatly simplified for example):

```
private string CreateChartJS(string ChartTitle, string SeriesField, string CategoryField)
{
    return "function createChart() { $(\"#chart\").kendoChart({ title: { text: \""+ChartTitle+"\", },     series: [{ field: \""+SeriesField+"\" }], categoryAxis: { field: \""+CategoryField+"\", } }); } ";
}
```

What I'm looking for is some type of converter/generator tool that can automatically create a simple C# wrapper class from the JavaScript library source code that I'm using. I am well aware of the fact that Telerik already makes a version of their charts for ASP.NET that includes custom made server side wrappers, this is not what I'm looking for as I'm just using the KendoUI as an example.

In the Chrome web developer tools console I can examine the created KendoUI Chart and view all of its properties:

[image: KendoChart in Chrome Console]

The tool I'm looking for should be able to create a simple C# class out of the properties that are exposed in the screenshot above (in this case, the group of properties I'm looking to configure are the child items of the 'Options' object).

Example of what the generated C# class might look like (greatly simplified for example):

```
public class KendoChartWrapper
{    
    public class options
    {
        public bool autoBind { get; set; }
        public class axisDefaults { }
        public class categoryAxies { }
        public class chartArea { }
        public class dataSource { }
        public class legend { }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public class navigator { }
        public class plotArea { }
        public string prefix { get; set; }
        public string renderAs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This would allow me to create my chart JavaScript by creating an instance of the class in C# and serializing  the result. What I'm looking for should be able to create these simple C# classes given the source code of any javascript library (examples: jQuery, jQuery UI, etc...).

I'm guessing that there is already an existing tool that can do this, I just don't know what it is called. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found exactly what I was looking for: http://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Is it just the options you want as a JavaScript object? If it is just the options you want then on the server you can serialize the object to a JSON using:

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.Serialize(YourObject)
```

Then when you receive this at the Javascript end you can turn this into a JavaScript object and use it for your chart options using:

```
var options = JSON.parse(json);
$("#chart").kendoChart(options);
```

Available on modern browsers and you can get a fallback for older browsers

Comment: I want the inverse. I want to automatically generate a C# class that contains the properties of an object from JavaScript code. I already know how to do the serialization.